# Concatenate/combine two columns into one for Pandas dataframe when axis = 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe:

```
d_test = {
    'c1' : ['a', 'b', np.nan, 'c'],
    'c2' : ['d', np.nan, 'e', 'f'],
    'test': [1,2,3,4],
}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(d_test)
```

And I want to concatenate columns `c1` and `c2` in one and have following resulted dataframe:

```
a 1
b 2
c 4
d 1
e 3
f 4
```

I tired to use

```
pd.concat([df_test.c1 , df_test.c2], axis = 0)
```

to generate such a column but have no idea how to keep 'test' column as well during concationation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `melt`

```
df_test.melt('test').dropna()[['value', 'test']]
```

result:

```
    value   test
0   a       1
1   b       2
3   c       4
4   d       1
6   e       3
7   f       4
```